# Subdivision surface working except for one edge loop

Tags: subdivision-surface

I hadn't been using Blender for several years. I forgot a ton of stuff.

I'm doing Subdivision Surface Modifier on an object. I can see it works, when I change the Subdivision resolution or click show/hide in viewport, except for one edge loop. See attached image.

The caps happened to be disconnected from the main cylinder-like body of the object. So I Merged them By Distance. Now it's all one connected mesh. But Subdivision Surface works on all but this Merged edge loop.

Any hints on why this is happening?

[image: Subdivision Surface Modifier not working on one Edge Loop]

Comment: Hello could you please share your object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normals are inverted, select all and recalculate the normals (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>)